# How to show textInput and keyboard programmatically

Tags: expo, chatbot, react-native-gifted-chat

I'm in charge to a build a react-native **chatbot** app, that must help users to signup during the discussion.

The chat must start with a greeting message and few *quick-replies*, in which we find a "Sign me up" option. When the user presses that option, the bot asks hem to write an email address in order to start the process.

I've made a little project based on [the example](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/tree/master/example) available on react-native-gifted-chat repository.

Please use this link to get to my code: https://github.com/firas1220/react-native-chatbot

I'd appreciate if someone gives some hand or maybe we can add improvements and transform the repo into something original .

This question might help some people facing similar situations.

As an attachment, a demo in GIF image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add an InputText (https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput) and then to `ref.current.focus()`

Something like this:

```js
const inputRef = useRef();

const onAction = () => {
  inputRef.current.focus();
}

<InputText ref={inputRef} value=... />
```